# How to generate Component-preload.js file for Fiori App in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori, s4hana, ui5-tooling

I have a Fiori app that I need to customize in VS Code. I downloaded the app from SE38 by executing /UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD. I then connected the app to the server and migrated it via VSCode with the help of Fiori Tools. I couldn't find a Component-preload.js file among the downloaded project files.

I made a change to my app and wanted to test it in the newly launched app via local https server. However, I'm getting the below errors:

[image]

How do I generate a Component-preload.js file in VSCode?

TIA,
Ruzna

Comment: The component-preload allows you to bundle your application to have a single file to load.
It is useful for a productive version of your application.
If you want to test your application with a Component-preload you must build your application with ui5 tooling.

ui5 build --config=ui5.yaml --clean-dest --dest dist

And then start the application from the sepifier file after the --dest argument

Comment: It doesnt work. i'm not sure if its the HTTPs url that I used when connecting the SAP system is causing this.